# Dopped FK constraint to delete a record and cannot add it back after. MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I needed to drop some FK constraints in order to delete a row in a table but I want to add it back after I deleted but I get this error when I try to add it back in:

**Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fail...**

I know this error happens when you try to insert a corresponding key that does not exist but unclear why I'm getting this error when trying to add a constraint back to the table?  It is a mapping table so maybe there is some issue with that?

Here is the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE `franchise_state` (
 `franchise_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`franchise_id`,`state_id`),
 KEY `fk_state_id_franchise_state` (`state_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_franchise_id_franchise_state` FOREIGN KEY (`franchise_id`) REFERENCES `franchise` (`franchise_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_state_id_franchise_state` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `states` (`state_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then I ran this alter table statement:

```
alter table franchise_state drop foreign key fk_franchise_id_franchise_state
```

Now the table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `franchise_state` (
 `franchise_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`franchise_id`,`state_id`),
 KEY `fk_state_id_franchise_state` (`state_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_state_id_franchise_state` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `states` (`state_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Ok at this point I delete the row in franchise table (and delete all the corresponding franchise_id rows in franchise_state) and attempt to put the constraint back in with this:

```
ALTER TABLE franchise_state ADD CONSTRAINT fk_franchise_id_franchise_state FOREIGN KEY (franchise_id) REFERENCES franchise(franchise_id);
```

But as stated at the start I get "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign..."??

Comment: Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and take a look at the LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR section. It should give you some more clues about what's wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't need to drop a foreign key just to delete data. You should have deleted child rows first, then delete the parent row in `franchise`.

Comment: alright let me check it out.  One sec

Comment: ok.  Got a really log error description with hex codes.  Too big to paste here.  I will add some key lines that might help: DATA TUPLE: 4 fields;
0: len 4; hex 80000080; asc     ;;
1: len 4; hex 80000033; asc    3;;
2: len 6; hex 000000617bde; asc    a{ ;;
3: len 7; hex af00001f33101a; asc

Comment: does this mean there might be 4 rows in franchise table that need to be deleted first?  I wonder where it tells you the actual data?

Comment: Find the missing franchise_id: `select franchise_id from franchise_state left join franchise using(franchise_id) where franchise.franchise_id is null;`

Comment: Figured it out.  There were a few franchises I deleted previously and forgot to delete corresponding rows in franchise_state table.  Good to go now.  Appreciate your help

Comment: ahh yes duh.  Should have thought of that

Comment: and also yes I'll just delete child rows first.  Another thing I should of done first.  I'm learning!

Comment: if you want to make an answer I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query to help find the missing rows in the parent `franchise` table:

```
select franchise_id 
from franchise_state 
left join franchise using(franchise_id) 
where franchise.franchise_id is null;
```

If there are any missing rows in the parent table, creating a foreign key will fail.